# Ng-repeat over array objects form inputs

Tags: angularjs

```
[{"id":1,"inputfieldbox":[{"id":1},{"id":2}]},{"id":2,"inputfieldbox":{"id":1}}]
```

I want to use NG-repeat to iterate a form.

Inputfield box denotes the number of input box i will have
id denotes the number of field group i will have.

So in example above, I would have 2 field group. First field group will have 2 input while the last will have only 1.

Comment: Nested JSON isn't a good candidate for using `ng-repeat`.

Comment: OK. Try doing it, and come back here if you have a concrete question.

Comment: Can you expand array object more.

Comment: yup! i have a button to add input/fieldset

Answer (score 0):

Use nested ng-repeat like this,

```
<ul ng-repeat='object in formData'>
<li ng-repeat='items in object.inputfieldbox'>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how do i translate that to a select drop down menu?

Comment: What i understood from the problem, you need first ng-repeat for making form fields and second ng-repeat for options in dropdown. Is it so?

Comment: YES! first ng-repeat for fieldset. 2nd ng-repeat for dropdown

Comment: Try this, 
<fieldset ng-repeat='let object in array'>
<legend>{{object.id}} </legend>
<select ng-repeat='let optionItem in object.inputfieldbox>
<option value={{optionItem.id}}>{{optionItem.id}}  </option>
</select>
</fieldset>